# Formula to get the month of the last value

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have sales data by customer as follows:

```
| - | A             | B      | C      | D      | E      | F      | G      |
|---|---------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 1 | Customer Name | Jan-18 | Feb-18 | Mar-18 | Apr-18 | May-18 | Jun-18 |
| 2 | Mr.A          | 1000   | 500    | 0      | 200    | 0      | 0      |
| 3 | Mr.B          | 0      | 300    | 200    | 0      | 0      | 100    |
```

I need the formula to know the last sales of the respective customer booked (the name of the month)

in this case, `Mr. A` last order is in Apr-18 while `Mr.B` is in Jun-18.

I have 2,000 plus customer and sales data since Apr 2016 up to last month, it will be a huge time saving to have a formula to help.

Comment: pls include screenshot from excel for better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your 'months' are dates, not Text. Courtesy [@barry houdini](https://superuser.com/users/111645/barry-houdini):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:G2<>0),B$1:G$1)
```

in Row2 and copied down to suit, formatted `mmm-yy`.

[Ref](https://superuser.com/a/937584/145438)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `LOOKUP()` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52529618/6387479), not sure what impact it has performance-wise as both need to create an array but I would take a stab in the dark that this is less performant:

`=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,,MAX((B2:G2<>0)*COLUMN(B2:G2)-1))` - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Ofcourse this could be edited to a dual lookup on the customer too:

`=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,,MAX(INDEX(($B$2:$G$3<>0)*COLUMN($B$2:$G$3)-1,MATCH("Mr.B",$A$2:$A$3,0),0)))`

This doesn't require the CSE as `INDEX()` handles the array manipulation

Comment: I'm sorry I've tried it out, it didn't work, I just curious with this formula, however I've tried @pnuts answer, it works, thanks...